# Load animated GIF in Photoshop CS4

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, cs4

Older versions of Photoshop had ImageReady that allowed you to import GIFs and load each frame as a layer. Apparently that doesn't exist anymore and I really need it. I'm using CS4.

I have tried loading it into GIMP and saving as a PSD, but that resulted in the layers being flattened. I tried many image converters, but they either only converted the first frame, or created a separate PSD for each frame...

Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adobe really hosed CS3 and CS4 where this is concerned.

To open an animated gif with Photoshop CS3 or CS4 choose File > Import > Video Frames to Layers. This will open the animation but in my experience you lose all transparency for the frames. So you have to reconstruct the transparency if it exists. **There is simply no way to open a transparent animated gif and retain both frames and transparency with Photoshop CS# or CS4.**

It may be worth your while to go find some freeware which will open the gif and save it as a PSD. If I remember correctly, at the time, I found a $5 app that did just that and solved the issue. I can't recall the app name now though. I simply found it by searching for "edit Animated Gif" on download sites.

**This issue was fixed in Photoshop CS5.** Photoshop CS5+ will open transparent animated gifs without issue.

Comment: To add to your answer, Scott, you won't be able to see the .GIF file until you put the `*` character into the file name field and pressing enter.

Comment: I don't appear to have that option...

Comment: It's been a while. It may only work with CS4 Extended. If you post the animation you need to open somewhere, I'd be happy to open it and resave it as a .psd for you. @Johannes not on the Mac :) Actually I can't test much here. CS4 runs a bit less-than-ideal on Mac OS 10.7.

Comment: Make sure you're sunning the 32-bit version of photoshop, Kolink, it does not appear to appear in the 64-bit version.

Comment: Good catch :) I wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: @Scott Nice of you to offer, but I have 700+ gifs that I want to be able to open as PSDs should I need them.

Comment: @Johannes Ah, I was running the 64-bit version. I'll check the 32-bit.